# Undefined Index com conexão Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

Por alguma razão, meu código está resultando no erro

> Notice: Undefined Index IRRAD

ao tentar realizar uma consulta no banco de dados Oracle. O código em PHP que estou utilizando:

```
set_time_limit( 600 );
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');    
$query2 = 'SELECT \'0 - 300\' as intervalo, ROUND(SUM('.$irradInc.')/3600000, 2) as irrad FROM '.$tabela.' WHERE '.$irradInc.' BETWEEN 0 AND 300 AND TS_SAMPLETM BETWEEN TO_DATE(\''.$data1.'\', \'DD/MM/YY\') AND TO_DATE(\''.($data2->format('d/m/y')).'\', \'DD/MM/YY\')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT \'300 - 700\', ROUND(SUM('.$irradInc.')/3600000, 2) FROM '.$tabela.' WHERE '.$irradInc.' BETWEEN 300 AND 700 AND TS_SAMPLETM BETWEEN TO_DATE(\''.$data1.'\', \'DD/MM/YY\') AND TO_DATE(\''.($data2->format('d/m/y')).'\', \'DD/MM/YY\')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT \'700 - 1000\', ROUND(SUM('.$irradInc.')/3600000, 2) FROM '.$tabela.' WHERE '.$irradInc.' BETWEEN 700 AND 1000 AND TS_SAMPLETM BETWEEN TO_DATE(\''.$data1.'\', \'DD/MM/YY\') AND TO_DATE(\''.($data2->format('d/m/y')).'\', \'DD/MM/YY\')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT \'1000 - 1200\', ROUND(SUM('.$irradInc.')/3600000, 2) FROM '.$tabela.' WHERE '.$irradInc.' BETWEEN 1000 AND 1200 AND TS_SAMPLETM BETWEEN TO_DATE(\''.$data1.'\', \'DD/MM/YY\') AND TO_DATE(\''.($data2->format('d/m/y')).'\', \'DD/MM/YY\')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT \'> 1200\', ROUND(SUM('.$irradInc.')/3600000, 2) FROM '.$tabela.' WHERE '.$irradInc.' > 1200 AND TS_SAMPLETM BETWEEN TO_DATE(\''.$data1.'\', \'DD/MM/YY\') AND TO_DATE(\''.($data2->format('d/m/y')).'\', \'DD/MM/YY\')';
    //echo $query2;
    $conn = oci_connect('****', '***', '****');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query2);
    oci_execute($stid);
    $array = array();
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) {
        array_push(
                $array,
                array(
                'value' => $row['irrad'],
                'label' => $row['INTERVALO']
                 )
             );


        unset($row);  
    }
```

A query que estou executando é:

```
SELECT \'0 - 300\' as intervalo, ROUND(SUM('.$irradInc.')/3600000, 2) as irrad FROM '.$tabela.' WHERE '.$irradInc.' BETWEEN 0 AND 300 AND TS_SAMPLETM BETWEEN TO_DATE(\''.$data1.'\', \'DD/MM/YY\') AND TO_DATE(\''.($data2->format('d/m/y')).'\', \'DD/MM/YY\')
```

Utilizando a query diretamente no SQL Developer da Oracle, o resultado vem corretamente, com os nomes das colunas como está no código em PHP. O index Intervalo funciona corretamente, porém, o index IRRAD ele acusa o erro citado.

Existe alguma regra a ser seguida para ler os cabeçalhos ou tem algo errado no código?

Comment: Tenta recuperar o nome em caixa baixa, `$row['irrad']`

Comment: continua com o Undefined Index. Outras consultas no mesmo molde estão rodando sem problemas. Também nunca tive problemas com consulta MySQL. Vou postar o resto do código para ver se há alguma interferência

Comment: isso, pode ajudar.

Comment: Quando vc faz `print_r($row);` aparece o que? pode colocar nos comentários mesmo o resultado.

Comment: Array ( [INTERVALO] => 0 - 300 )

Comment: Remova o alias do `irrad` e rode novamente o print_r, espero que venha algo diferente.

Comment: Continua apenas com o index INTERVALO :/

Comment: Acho que entendi. Por algum motivo estava retornando NULL para a coluna do IRRAD e, quando a consulta retorna NULL, o `$row` não recebe a coluna.

Comment: Não sei se o oracle tem alguma particularidade mas acredito que a coluna deveria ser definida com null e não simplesmente não existir.

Comment: Adicionei um verificador para avaliar se retorna null e está funcionando corretamente. Adiciono uma resposta com o código funcional ou edito a pergunta? Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se resolveu o problema, crie uma resposta :).

Answer (score 1):

O problema era que, quando a consulta retornava valor **NULL**, a variável `$row` não recebia o index desta coluna. Portanto, quando ia fazer a leitura do `$row['IRRAD']`, estava resultando em *Undefined Index*.

Para corrigir, adicionei uma linha de verificação:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) {
    //print_r($row);
    if(!oci_field_is_null( $stid , 'IRRAD' )){
        array_push(
            $array,
            array(
            'value' => round(($row['IRRAD']/$irradTotal)*100, 2),
            'label' => $row['INTERVALO']
             )
         );
    }   


    unset($row);  
}
```

O comando [oci_field_is_null](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.oci-field-is-null.php) retorna verdadeiro se o campo em análise for NULL e falso caso o campo contenha algum valor.

Answer (score 1):

Além da solução já apresentada, há também estas:

Forçar o retorno de colunas com valores NULL informando isso em [$mode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.oci-fetch-array.php) de qualquer oci_fetch_*

```
oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)
```

Evitar retornar nulo para um campo qualquer na consulta com o comando [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm)

```
$query2 = 'SELECT \'0 - 300\' as intervalo, COALESCE(ROUND(SUM('.$irradInc.')/3600000, 2), 0) as irrad FROM(...)
```

Comment: Não conheço  oracle, nesse caso quando uma coluna retorna null, ele simplesmente não à adiciona no retorno da consulta?

Comment: Creio que isso é o comportamento do Client Oracle (geralmente Instant Client) e não do SGDB propriamente dito. Deve ser alguma especificação que as extensões OCI e PDO_OCI seguem.